# RSpec Failure: "Static Pages X should have title X" -- Tried with have_xpath & have_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I've been scouring the web & Stack Overflow to tr and figure out how to get these tests working. I'm brand new to Ruby & to Rails, I'm simply following along Hartl's tutorial - copy pasting most of the code to see how it all falls together in the end.

Now, I'm getting stuck in section 3.3 "Slightly Dynamic Pages".

This is the error I'm recieving:

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec --no-color spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
F.F.F.

Failures:

  1) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
 Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title',
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
 Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title',
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages Home page should have the title 'Home'
 Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title',
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.09 seconds
6 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:42 # Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:27 # Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12 # Static pages Home page should have the title 'Home'

Randomized with seed 25648
```

The error is occuring as soon as I swtich from this HTML Structure (in my About/Home/Help.html.erb files):

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Sample App</h1>
    <p>
      This is the home page for the
      <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
      sample application.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**To this:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
  <p>
     This is the home page for the
     <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
     sample application.
  </p>
```

Other related files:

**Application.html.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do


describe "Home page" do
  it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
  end

  it "should have the title 'Home'" do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    page.should have_selector('title',
                    :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")

     // The line below is something I tried replacing the page.should have_selector with
    // page.should have_xpath("//title", :text => "Home")
  end
end

.... (other describe pages, same structure)

end
```

I might've just gone blind over the course of copying/pasting/reading from Hartl's tutorial, but I am pretty damn sure it looks the same way as he described it.

I've done my best at looking for a solution to this, but alas I haven't been able to figure it out, so here goes!

Cheers!

Edit: Answer to Fiona #1

On this url : "http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home"

The document title is nothing.

The source of the document looks like this:

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

There is no doctype, head, body or title declaration in the source.

Comment: What is the title of the page when you visit '/static_pages/home' in a browser window?

Comment: Formatting in here didn't end up the way I wanted. Answering your question in the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails to pick up the layout file, the application.html.erb file should be in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that insight. The application.html.erb was actually located in app/views/ in my case. Solved!

Comment: That solved my identical problem as well. Boy, Rails is fiddly and changes between versions...