# RSpec Failure: Page should have title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run very simple RSpec tests following the Rails Tutorial and they surprisingly fail when they're not supposed to.

[Fiona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897970/rspec-failure-static-pages-x-should-have-title-x-tried-with-have-xpath-h)  somewhere else suggested to move the file application.html.erb in app/views/layouts but mine is already there.

[Zetetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971449/verifying-page-title-with-rspec) suggested to add "render views" but I did and nothing changed.

The versions of the sw i'm using are as follows:

- rvm 1.25.26
- rspec 3.0.1
- ruby 1.9.3p547
- Rails 4.1.1

I get the following failure message:

```
$>rspec spec/requests/pages_spec.rb
F

Failures:

1) Pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
 Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
   expected #has_selector?("h1", {:text=>"Sample App"}) to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Deprecation Warnings:

Requiring `rspec/autorun` when running RSpec via the `rspec` command is deprecated. Called from /home/iammyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'.

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from /home/iammyr/railsgirls-app/projects/galway_june2014/spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'.


Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:7 # Pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
```

One difference from the tutorial is that rather than generating those static pages with "rails generate static_pages" I did run "rails generate controller pages home help" but that shouldn't have to do with the rspec result, imho.

The files look as follow.
**pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Pages" do
  render_views
  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/pages/home'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
   This is the home page.
</p>
```

Thanks a million to whomever would like to help me! thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should first move the spec from requests to features folder [see changes in capybara](http://www.andylindeman.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html)

I guess it will fix it (remember having a similar one)
If not debug it with pry and in Firefox with selenium driver

```
 #Gemfile
  gem 'pry-rails'

  #spec
  it "should have the h1 'Sample App'", :js => true do
  visit '/pages/home'
  binding.pry
  page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
end
```

Firefox should start and render the page
Then in debug mode check the capybara selector

```
   page.all(:css, 'h1')
```

Comment: thanks a million user1035375! Unfortunately, moving the test to a new spec/features folder didn't solve the issue: it is still failing. Thanks a lot for mentioning pry and selenium cause I've learned a lot by searching for info around them. However, so far I have run pry on sample classes but not on the rspec. figuring out how to do it at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't define `capybara` or another driver. Then you try `content` instead of `text`:

```
page.should have_selector('h1', :content => 'Sample App')
```

Comment: thanks a million for your help! Unfortunately that didn't work. I got: ArgumentError:
       invalid keys :content, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait

Comment: nope :/ I'm trying to figure out how to use pry at the moment, as suggested in the other comment ;)